# Can't find the include files for classic asp site

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I'm having problems with an old classic asp site that I'm trying to get set up in a dev environment. I get the following error at the line for the include files.

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Here's my setup:

- I'm running IIS 7 on Win 7.
- I have an app pool `ControlPanel` set up with No managed code and classic pipeline
- My website `ControlPanel` configured under default websites pointing to my project directory "C:\Projects\uk_CP\uk_AU\au"

Many of the pages work, I can log in, click on a link to a feedback form, but eventually I get the above error.

My feedback form is located at "C:\Projects\uk_CP\uk_Au\au\feedbackform_admin\dataview_master.asp"
It has two include files:

```
<!--#include file="../inc/adovbs.inc" -->
<!--#include file="../inc/incCreateConn.asp" -->
```

this are correctly located in "C:\Projects\uk_CP\uk_Au\au\inc\"

Is perhaps my IIS configured incorrectly that throws off my working directory? Is there a useful way to troubleshoot the path it's looking at? I haven't work in classic asp in 10 years and it is not something I want to become an expert in, but I do need to get this figured out and I've killed too much time as it is.

Obviously this is an issue with my setup since it does work in production...

Comment: Do you have friendly error messages turned on in your browser?  And do you have IIS set up to send error messages to the browser?

Comment: how do I go about doing that? Detailed Errors is turned on, but not sure about anything else.

Comment: OK, just turned on "send error messages to browser" in iis.

Comment: See here:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/  See if "Send Errors To Browser" is true or false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your ASP-configuration you must enable the setting 'Allow parent paths'

Comment: this may have done it. I'm still getting the error, but it doesn't seem to be from the includes.